# How can I vertical align images in slick slider

Tags: html, css

I have a slick slider, and i want to vertical align the images in the 
`a` element. I tried `vertical-align:middle;` with height:100%; and tried some more, but I haven't find the solution yet. I also tried with `<span class="helper"></span` like i found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div) solution on stackoverflow([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4570/)). I hope you guys can help me out.

My HTML for the slider is the following:

```css
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center text-secondary">Partners</h2>
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/26/17/33/landscape-1622739_960_720.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/02/52/tree-2067496__340.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/26/17/33/landscape-1622739_960_720.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/02/52/tree-2067496__340.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/26/17/33/landscape-1622739_960_720.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/02/52/tree-2067496__340.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/26/17/33/landscape-1622739_960_720.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="slide"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/02/52/tree-2067496__340.jpg"></a>
   </section>
</div>
```

Ofcourse jQuery and slick.js are included.
You can see the demo right [here](https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE), but with square images. My images are not square so i need to vertical align the images in the horizontal slider.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you add this in your jquery `$( ".slick-slide" ).each(function( index ) {

$( this ).css('margin-top',($('.slider').height()-$(this).height())/2+'px' );
});`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @xmastertje . Working for me!

Comment: I will put this as an answer could you please accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Jquery. If you add the following code it will fix your problem.
It gives all the images a height and a position.

```
$( ".slick-slide" ).each(function( index ) { 
   $( this ).css('margin-top',
   ($('.slider').height()-$(this).height())/2+'px' );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your slick function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.customer-logos').slick({
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1500,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
  vertical: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 520,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3
        }
    }]
});
```

});

`vertical: true;` <--- only add this. This will set your images vertical

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but i meant to vertical-align the images to the middle in a horizontal slider.

Comment: right got your point. you can resolve your problem using CSS Flex property. Use this

.slider {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  align-items: center;}

Play with height, it will work :) .